# Sftp in Chef doesn't work

Tags: windows, chef-infra, sftp, chef-recipe

I'm trying to download a remote file over sftp, and I wrote this:

```
remote_file 'C:/adnet/mercury_package/Adnet.EASS.zip' do
  source 'sftp://myusername:mypassword@packages.domain.com:22/package/Adnet.EASS.zip'
  action :create
end
```

and the output is:

```
SocketError
-----------
getaddrinfo: No such host is known.
```

I tried to remove username and password from the URI, and put them in remote_user and remote_password, but then it complains about not having the userinfo:

```
"no userinfo provided in the sftp URI"
```

[The stacktrace is here](https://gist.github.com/Janjko/f92229e9a4159a60ba5f3fd172ece7f2)

Answer (score 0):

The problem was in single quotes around the source. It works like this:

```
remote_file 'C:/adnet/mercury_package/Adnet.EASS.zip' do
  source "sftp://myusername:mypassword@packages.domain.com:22/package/Adnet.EASS.zip"
  action :create
end
```

Comment: That isn't possible so something else must have been wrong.